# compute conditional expectation given density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with density

$$
p(x) = \frac{3}{4}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x) + \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{(-1,0)}(x).
$$
Define $Y := |X|$. How can I show that

$$
\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = \frac{Y}{2}.
$$

Comment: I would recommend drawing a picture of the density function for yourself. This may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
X = X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}} +  X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}},
$$
$X=Y$ on $\{X\geqslant0\}$, and $X=-Y$ on $\{X<0\}$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid Y] &= \mathbb E[X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}} +  X\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}}\mid Y]\\
&= \mathbb E[Y\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}}\mid Y] +\mathbb E[-Y\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}}\mid Y]\\
&= Y\cdot \mathbb E[\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}}-1_{\{X<0\}}\mid Y]\\
&= Y\cdot(\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant0\}}] - E[\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}}])\\
&= Y\cdot(\mathbb P(X\geqslant0)-\mathbb P(X<0))\\
&= Y\cdot(3/4 - 1/4)\\
&= \frac Y2.
\end{align}